# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails with csv import

Tags: mysql, sql

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sysmexhospital`.`referral`, CONSTRAINT `referral_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`doctorFirstName`, `doctorLastName`) REFERENCES `doctor` (`doctorFirstName`, `doctorLastName`))

I am getting this error every time I try and load data from a csv file into a table.

Table Code

```
Create table Doctor
(
doctorFirstName Varchar(15),
doctorLastName Varchar(15),
primary key (doctorFirstName,doctorLastName)
)engine Innodb;

-- Load Doctor file
load data local infile 'C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/SQL Database Assignment/Data/Doctor.csv'
into table Doctor
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
(doctorFirstName,doctorLastName);

Create table Referral
(
referralDate date,
patientNHI char(7),
referredFrom Varchar(15),
ageAtReferral Integer,
daysWaiting Integer,
doctorFirstName Varchar(15),
doctorLastName Varchar(15),
primary key (referralDate, patientNHI),
foreign key (doctorFirstName, doctorLastName) references Doctor (doctorFirstName, doctorLastName),
foreign key (patientNHI) references Patient (patientNHI)
)engine Innodb;

-- Load Referral file
load data local infile 'C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/SQL Database Assignment/Data/Referral.csv'
into table Referral
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
(referralDate,referredFrom,doctorFirstName, doctorLastName,patientNHI);
```

Example of data from Referral.csv

```
2016-05-04;GP;Donald;Clinton;YDV0095
2016-06-25;GP;Ralph;Smith;ISJ1177
2016-02-20;GP;Bill;Key;NKX8076
2016-01-12;GP;Lesley;Young;BBB5629
2015-10-14;GP;Donald;Clinton;PLL2090
2015-12-30;Internal;Amit;Oliver;ODR2838
```

Example of data from Doctor.csv (Whats currently loaded in the Doctor Table)

```
Amit;Oliver
Bill;Key
Donald;Clinton
Hilary;Trump
John;Richards
John;English
Lesley;Young
Linda;Moore
Michael;Scott
Ralph;Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the rows in referrals is referencing a doctor that does not exist in the doctors table. More specifically, you might have a referral with a doctor named "John Smith", but they don't exist in the doctors table.

Comment: I tried removing all rows in Referrals except for 1 and ensured the name existed in the Doctor table but I still received the same error. Sorry for the images. I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

your doctor table does not have values for doctorFirstName, doctorLastName which you are trying to insert in a Refferal table.

below link has solution, how to fix your issue.

[MySQL .csv load failing due to "Cannot add or update a child row: foreign key constraint fails"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470450/mysql-csv-load-failing-due-to-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-foreign-key-co)

Comment: In the 2nd image the right hand csv file is what was imported into the Doctor table. This is verified by doing a query https://i.imgur.com/nojPDbu.png. The names match perfectly to what is being inserted into the Referral table

Comment: say i doctor name is john smith and is not there in doctor table but you are trying insert john smith in Referral table you get this kind of error

Comment: I've updated my main post to be a bit more clear. The data is definitely already existing in the Doctor Table

Comment: next one is to check foreign key (patientNHI) references Patient (patientNHI), whether patient table has all patientNHI that you are trying  to insert in referral table

Comment: If I remove trying to insert doctorFirstName and doctorLastName I also get the same error but for the patientNHI

Comment: It seems that setting SET foreign_key_checks = 0 allows the data to be entered without any errors. Is it safe to just enter the data with this setting and revert it after, or will this cause errors in the future?

Comment: basically it will not do any checks with foriegn keys and you can revert back to SET foreign_key_checks = 1